# structural adder (2 kinds) with numeric_std

Tags: vhdl, instance

I have the following VHDL code to implement an adder using structural architecture, so first i have to make a basic adder using the package numeric_std in two .vhd files:

this is the adder.vhd

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
 use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity adder is
generic(
                g_width : natural := 32);
port(
            cin : in std_logic;
            op1 : in std_logic_vector (g_width-1 downto 0);
            op2 : in std_logic_vector (g_width-1 downto 0);
            add : out std_logic_vector (g_width downto 0));
end adder;
```

and then the rtl.vhd:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

architecture rtl of adder is

begin

   add <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(op1), g_width+1) + resize(unsigned(op2), g_width+1) + unsigned'(0=>cin));
end rtl;
```

everything it's ok here, but then i have to make another adder (cpa.vhd , which have architecture of adder using instances of a new enitty fa.vhd(which is a new file)
so here's the code:

fa.vhd:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity fa is
port(   ope1 : in std_logic;
        ope2 : in std_logic;
        cin : in std_logic;
        cout : out std_logic;
        sum : out std_logic);
end entity fa;
```

cpa.vhd:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

architecture cpa of adder is

component fa is 
port(   ope1 : in std_logic;
        ope2 : in std_logic;
        cin : in std_logic;
        cout : out std_logic;
        sum : out std_logic);
end component;
signal carry : std_logic_vector(g_width downto 0);

begin

p_cpa : for i in 0 to g_width-1 generate
    i_fa : fa port map(
                            ope1=>op1(i),
                            ope2=>op2(i),
                            cin=>carry(i),
                            sum=>add(i),
                            cout=>carry(i+1));
end generate p_cpa;
end cpa;
```

so the problem is that it doesn't work , when i run the tb it seems unsigned:

[image: waveform image]

I don't know where is the problem.

i forgot the TB :

```
library ieee;

use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;

entity tb_adder is
end tb_adder;

architecture beh of tb_adder is
  constant c_width : natural := 32;
  constant c_upper_bound : natural := (2**16)-1;
  component adder
    generic(
      g_width : natural := 16
      );
    port(
      cin : in  std_logic;
      op1 : in  std_logic_vector(g_width-1 downto 0);
      op2 : in  std_logic_vector(g_width-1 downto 0);
      add : out std_logic_vector(g_width downto 0)
      );
  end component;

-- Inputs
  signal cin : std_logic;
  signal op1 : std_logic_vector(c_width-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal op2 : std_logic_vector(c_width-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');

-- Outputs
  signal res      : std_logic_vector(c_width downto 0);
  signal res_xpct : std_logic_vector(c_width downto 0);


begin
--Instance 
  dut : adder generic map (
    g_width => c_width
     )
     port map (
    cin => cin,
    op1 => op1,
    op2 => op2,
    add => res
    );

  cin <= '0';

  p_stim : process
    variable v_i : natural := 0;
    variable v_j : natural := 0;
  begin
    i_loop : for v_i in 0 to c_upper_bound loop
      j_loop : for v_j in 0 to c_upper_bound loop
        op1      <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(v_i, c_width));
        op2      <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(v_j, c_width));
        res_xpct <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(v_i + v_j, c_width+1));
        wait for 10 ns;
        assert res = res_xpct
          report "Error: wrong operation"
          severity error;
        wait for 10 ns;
      end loop j_loop;
    end loop i_loop;
    wait;
  end process p_stim;

end beh;
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: This isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without the architecture for fa, your waveform shows inputs are all 'U's (('U' - Uninitialized) ), which results in all 'U' outputs, nor have you described what you've done to solve the problem so far. How is `adder` port `cin` introduced to the first `fa`'s `cin in `p_cpa`? A concurrent assignment `carry(0) <= cin;` is needed. You don't need context clauses replicated in architectures. Show your testbench.

Comment: @kriptor of course the signals are all unintialized, you never initialized them.  You need to create a process in your testbench to generate the inputs to the logic you want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wrote a working `fa` architecture and a test bench, and made a couple of changes to the `cpa` architecture:

```
architecture foo of fa is       -- added architecture
begin
    sum <= ope1 xor ope2 xor cin;
    cout <= (ope1 and ope2) or
            (ope1 and cin) or
            (ope2 and cin);
end architecture;

architecture cpa of adder is

    component fa is 
        port (   
            ope1:  in  std_logic;
            ope2:  in  std_logic;
            cin:   in  std_logic;
            cout:  out std_logic;
            sum:   out std_logic
        );
    end component;

    signal carry:  std_logic_vector(g_width downto 0);

begin
    carry(0) <= cin;  -- added hook up the carry in
p_cpa:  
    for i in 0 to g_width-1 generate
i_fa:  
    fa 
        port map (
            ope1 => op1(i),
            ope2 => op2(i),
            cin => carry(i),
            sum => add(i),
            cout => carry(i+1)
        );
    end generate p_cpa;
    add(g_width) <= carry(g_width);  -- added hook up the carry out to the MSB
end architecture cpa;
```

The changes to the `cpa` architecture simply assign `cin` to `carry(0` and `carry(32)` to `add(32)`, the idea to build an adder compatible with your `rtl` architecture;

The testbench exercises both architectures at the same time:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity adder_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of adder_tb is
    constant g_width:   natural := 32;
    signal cin:         std_logic;
    signal op1:         std_logic_vector (g_width - 1 downto 0);
    signal op2:         std_logic_vector (g_width - 1 downto 0);
    signal add_rtl:     std_logic_vector (g_width downto 0);
    signal add_cpa:     std_logic_vector (g_width downto 0);
begin

DUT_rtl:
    entity work.adder (rtl)
        generic map (g_width)
        port map (
            cin => cin,
            op1 => op1,
            op2 => op2,
            add => add_rtl
        );

DUT_cpa:
    entity work.adder (cpa)
        generic map (g_width)
        port map (
            cin => cin,
            op1 => op1,
            op2 => op2,
            add => add_cpa
        );

STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        cin <= '0';
        op1 <= x"feedface";
        op2 <= x"deadbeef";
        wait for 10 ns;
        cin <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

And that gives us:

[image: adder_tb.png]

The same result on both adders, which tells us the two changes I made to architecture `cpa` were correct.

There isn't enough information present in your question to determine why the inputs on your waveform are all 'U's.

In the small testbench I wrote these are assigned in the STIMULUS process.

My 64 bit programmers calculator says the results are correct.

Comment: Thank u so much guy!! :)